# How to Find Items that Do NOT Have a pre-Pipe "Base" Value

Tags: sql, oracle, split, csv

I have a database with a column (obj_id) in a table (parts) where I SHOULD have an obj_id of 12345 that is a set for another row that would have 12345|.

So:

```
select obj_id from parts where obj_id like '12345%';
```

```
12345
12345|A
12345|B
12345|77
```

Now, someone violated the guideline and put in some items with the piped-value but not the base value w/o the pipe (e.g. 12378|J, 12378|8 but not 12378).

I need to know how to write a SQL query to find these piped-values that do NOT have their matching base (non-piped) value in the table.

Comment: please can you add a tag to indicate which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: I would like to point out that the decision to store multiple items in a single field always finds a creative way to come back and hurt you. The query would have been trivial to write in a properly designed schema, with each ID stored in a separate row. You wouldn't even have to write that query, because foreign key constraint would have prevented the "orphaned" values from being inserted in the first place. If you still have an option to rework your schema, it's probably a good idea to do it.

Comment: which dbms is it for please? supply some sample data and the expected result - perhaps create a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: The problem you have is **precisely** the reason why you shouldn't stored delimited values in a single column.

Answer (score 0):

Without some realistic sample data to work with it's hard to know what you really want. Below a 2 queries that may be of assistance, but perhaps it will also make you note how useful sample data can be:

See this working at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb68e/1)

```
CREATE TABLE PARTS
    (id int, OBJ_ID varchar2(200))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO PARTS (id, OBJ_ID)
         VALUES (1,'12345 12345|A 12345|B 12345|77')
    INTO PARTS (id, OBJ_ID)
         VALUES (2,'12346|A 12346|B 12346|77')
    INTO PARTS (id, OBJ_ID)
         VALUES (3,'12378|J, 12378|8')
    INTO PARTS (id, OBJ_ID)
         VALUES (4,NULL)
    INTO PARTS (id, OBJ_ID)
         VALUES (5,'fred. wilma, barney, betty')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
*
from PARTS p
where instr(p.OBJ_ID,' ') > instr(p.OBJ_ID,'|')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb68e/1/0)**:

```
| ID |                     OBJ_ID |
|----|----------------------------|
|  2 |   12346|A 12346|B 12346|77 |
|  3 |           12378|J, 12378|8 |
|  5 | fred. wilma, barney, betty |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select
       id, rn_a, regexp_substr (OBJ_ID_SPLIT, '[^|]+', 1, rn_b) as OBJ_ID_SPLIT
from (
      select 
             p.id, c1.rn_a, regexp_substr (p.OBJ_ID, '[^ ]+', 1, c1.rn_a) as OBJ_ID_SPLIT
      from PARTS p
      cross join (select rownum as rn_a
                   from (select max(length (regexp_replace (OBJ_ID, '[^|]+'))) + 1 as mx
                         from PARTS
                        )
                connect by level <= mx) c1
      where p.OBJ_ID like '%|%'       
      ) d
cross join (select 1 rn_b from dual union all select 2 from dual) c2
order by id, rn_a
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb68e/1/1)**:

```
| ID | RN_A | OBJ_ID_SPLIT |
|----|------|--------------|
|  1 |    1 |        12345 |
|  1 |    1 |       (null) |
|  1 |    2 |        12345 |
|  1 |    2 |            A |
|  1 |    3 |        12345 |
|  1 |    3 |            B |
|  1 |    4 |        12345 |
|  1 |    4 |           77 |
|  2 |    1 |        12346 |
|  2 |    1 |            A |
|  2 |    2 |        12346 |
|  2 |    2 |            B |
|  2 |    3 |        12346 |
|  2 |    3 |           77 |
|  2 |    4 |       (null) |
|  3 |    1 |        12378 |
|  3 |    1 |           J, |
|  3 |    2 |        12378 |
|  3 |    2 |            8 |
|  3 |    3 |       (null) |
|  3 |    4 |       (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks, but the user cannot change the schema nor add tables.  And, the PKs are application managed; not set at the RDBMS level.

Comment: I believe you added that comment in the wrong place. However I  do also share the view that this concatenated string of values will be a source of massive frustration. Given that you are stuck with it perhaps you could comment on the queries? Are they at all helpful?  Can you provide better sample data?

Comment: Well, the comment covered all the respondents since I cannot use "create table" (thus: cannot add tables)

I think I'm going to have to resort to some combination of SQL to pull the data into a .TXT file and then use AWK & SED to do what I must.

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: by "in the wrong place" I meant, your comment belongs directly under the question near to the comments about redesign. Not under my suggested queries.